# npm "error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install different modules through npm.

```
c:\>npm install -g express
```

But I am getting following error message:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\FH Kiel\\WS 13\\Advanced Javascript\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\FH Kiel\\WS 13\\Advanced Javascript\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.14
3 info using node@v0.10.22
4 verbose node symlink D:\FH Kiel\WS 13\Advanced Javascript\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'express', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="express" args=["express",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'express',
7 verbose parsed url   path: 'express',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'express' }
8 silly lockFile f3c62de4-express express
9 verbose lock express C:\Users\MW\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\f3c62de4-express.lock
10 silly lockFile f3c62de4-express express
11 silly lockFile f3c62de4-express express
12 verbose addNamed [ 'express', '' ]
13 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
14 silly lockFile 64a534c1-express express@
15 verbose lock express@ C:\Users\MW\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\64a534c1-express.lock
16 silly addNameRange { name: 'express', range: '*', hasData: false }
17 verbose url raw express
18 verbose url resolving [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/', './express' ]
19 verbose url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/express
20 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 15:47:46
21 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
23 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 15:47:59
24 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
26 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 15:49:01
27 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
28 silly lockFile 64a534c1-express express@
29 silly lockFile 64a534c1-express express@
30 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
30 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
30 error network and is related to network connectivity.
30 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
30 error network
30 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
30 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
31 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
32 error command "D:\\FH Kiel\\WS 13\\Advanced Javascript\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\FH Kiel\\WS 13\\Advanced Javascript\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
33 error cwd D:\nodejs
34 error node -v v0.10.22
35 error npm -v 1.3.14
36 error syscall getaddrinfo
37 error code ENOTFOUND
38 error errno ENOTFOUND
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried the following solutions:

```
npm config set proxy http://usr:pwd@proxyname:port

npm config set https-proxy http://usr:pwd@proxyname:port

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have disabled the firewall and tried... nothing is working... There is no proxy setting so this should work (and is working in other computers)... I have installed node.js without any problem.

Thanx.

Update: Here is the windows host file :

```
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

I have also tried this solution found in other post:

```
npm install <packagename> --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Didn't work either :(

Comment: I did not read the whole post- sorry!

Comment: @alihaider No... I have tried this with other laptops and it is working fine.

Comment: can you try copying node_modules from a working computer and see if that works - just curious

Comment: @alihaider I haven't tried that... let me try...

Comment: what happens when you go to http://registry.npmjs.org/express in a browser? i havent used node for windows, do you need to do `npm install /g express`?

Comment: @Plato registry.npmjs.org/express works fine in the browser. isn't the code "npm install -g express"?

Comment: can you share your hosts file from windows?

Comment: @alihaider I have updated the question with Windows host file... and I tried the copying... it didn't work either..

Comment: I think the evidence of a stolen piece of Adobe software is particularly classy. +1

Comment: i wasnt sure if windows npm used `-flag` or the windows syntax `/flag`. do you get the same error with `npm install express`? (and re: the adobe line, perhaps OP simply doesn't like their software phoning home!)

Comment: does the problem persist with a new nodejs installation?  Also, can you try this and confirm that there is no proxy server: http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check

Comment: `There is no proxy setting so this should work` Then why are you setting proxy in your npm config ? Delete it. After proxy is unset retry.

Comment: I dont think there is a proxy problem because I am in the University and it is working for other students...

Comment: @user568109 This was one of the solution found in other question related to similar problem. So I was trying it to see if it will solve the problem. I have to try all possible solutions. :)

Also I have already tried npm config proxy delete... it still didn't work...

Comment: Don't know if you are using proxy or not in the university. Does net work from commandline, try `ping registry.npmjs.org` from windows cmd. Also get hold of one of your friends and ask him how ?

Comment: @user568109 Everything works except for the installation. I have even done the installation in one of my friend's laptop and the same thing worked. This is weird. There is no support from Phonegap guys too... I have emailed them...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did not find any solution for this but at the end I had to re-install my Windows. It is working now...

Comment: `npm config delete proxy` somehow did it for me

Answer (score 1):

**Remove any proxy that is set in your npm config file.**

At the command prompt, type `npm config edit`

This will open your *.npmrc* config file in your text editor.

Inside this file, go down to the proxy settings and if there are any entered settings there that you didn't configure yourself (such as `http://proxyurl/:port`), remove these settings, save the file, and go from there. This fixes this issue most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was setting the https-proxy but wasn't finding a way do it. Finally I tried the following in command prompt,

```
npm config edit
```

It opened the **.npmrc** file with default list of options commented with semi colons. Just had to remove the colon before https-proxy and entered the one provided to me from my company, hit save in the editor and everything worked.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had globall proxy too. Find that path on your pc.

```
C:\Users\(Your Username)\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\



find that file > npmignore 
(edit with text editor and than remove proxy lines.)
```

After that

```
npm install
```

That's it... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't use proxy but this error happened to me.

When I try visiting `registry.npmjs.org` in browser, it didn't show error

Editing npm config doesn't help me but

```
traceroute registry.npmjs.org
```

fix my issue

Answer (score -2):

The answer is pretty simple.

Step 1 : npm config edit. A txt file will popup

Step 2. Set the default npm registry as https://registry.npmjs.org

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, similar suggestions are already provided by older answers. Secondly, the OP mentioned that they tried to set the registry explicitly while install the package and that did not work. Next time, carefully review existing answers and add your answer when there is relevant information missing in existing answers or you have another approach that is not mentioned by any other answers.